# Convert CURL to javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch-api

How can I convert the following CURL command to javascript fetch?

```
curl --request GET -L -c --url https://tableau.example.com/trusted/DjabukX7T3u_bTUT0z7NdQ==:rQS3WF-ol-5snlDTOYlQ7pS2/t/site/views/workbook_name/view_name
```

I used the above command on my server is working.

Then I throw this command to many online CURL to javascript fetch converters, and they all return only like this:

```
fetch('https://tableau.example.com/trusted/DjabukX7T3u_bTUT0z7NdQ==:rQS3WF-ol-5snlDTOYlQ7pS2/t/site/views/workbook_name/view_name');
```

The above fetch code is not working for me.
and it returns
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch.`

I think the -c -L flag in CURL has the meaning for fetching:

https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-c

https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-L

What is the precise corresponding javascript fetch code for this CURL command?

thanks for the help from all of you.

Comment: How is it not working for you? Do you get an error message? If not, what does fetch return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the flags you are using for cURL are default behaviour for `fetch`.

Since you are making a cross-origin request you need to set the [`credentials` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#credentials) to `include` for cookies to be enabled.

Note that this will require the server to support a [CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

Comment: fetch(
      "https:/tableau.example.com/trusted/" +
        credential +
        "/t/site/views/workbook_name/view_name",
      {
        credentials: "include",
        method: "GET",
      }

Comment: is it like this?

Comment: but it seems still not working and shows Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Are there any other error messages? See my note in the answer about CORS preflights.

Comment: hmmm no other messages , just the error I mentioned above

Comment: The console usually does show a more specific error when "TypeError: Failed to fetch" is the only message exposed to the JS code itself.

Comment: oh ok it shows this :　Ensure CORS response header values are valid

Comment: Looks like you need to change the server side code on tableau.example.com to grant you permission then. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068

Comment: so it means server need to support CORS right? even though I can get content by CURL

Comment: Yes. Your cURL does not have access to the cookies already in the browsers of visitors to your website. Doing stuff across origins in browsers requires permission.

Comment: but CURL doesnt means javascript can get also, javascript need CORS to support. am I right?